# Link that ignores applink

Tags: android, html, applinks

Have a website, want to link to another page of it, and if the user has the android app installed give the option to view it in the website or app...

But not using the android "open with" screen, as often users will select "always" thus hiding the option.

So need a link that forces it to open in browser even though there is a app that could accept that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is using www.example.com for applinks and example.com for website

Ended up doing it differently.

Now if it detects "android" in the user agent making the request it shows a selection box with these options:
- link to the index page. This will offer to open in app if installed, or do nothing otherwise.
- download link to app
- close selection box and continue with web version.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: misread the question. This answer is not a valid solution.

You could also accomplish this with [Verified App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html). This would have users default to the app and not be shown the selection screen at all unless they go to Settings and override it.

Comment: The opposite, want to not open in app

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I didn't read carefully. If you've registered an app for a URI, I don't know of any way to force it NOT to be offered as a choice.

Comment: Yeah, seem to be finding that. One solution is using www.example.com for applinks and example.com for website

Comment: Sounds like a good solution! An extension of that option would be keeping your main website as web-only, and using a totally different domain to trigger app launches. Using a service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) would let you do that, while also simplifying your deep linking system.